# "selling mobile phone brand" or "mobile phone selling brand"?

Tags: grammar, word-order

"The other three top **selling mobile phone brands** between 2009 and 2013 were LG, ZTE and Apple"

I would like to ask if I can write " ... three top **mobile phone selling brands**..."

Is it grammatically correct? And if it is, is there any differences in meaning between the two ways of writing?

Many thanks.

Comment: It looks like "top" is modifying "selling, so I would keep them together.

Comment: "top-selling" is a compound adjective: the mobile phone brands which are the 'top sellers'.  You suggested sentence does not make sense to me: what is a "selling brand"?

Comment: I get your point because top selling is quite common and natural, but I tend to think "top" is modifying "Brands", and top's role in this sentence is just the same as those of "mobile phone" and "selling" which are playing as adjectives

Comment: If you would like to have it modify "brands", you have to remove "selling". It doesn't sound natural.

Answer (score 1):

As others highlighted, consider "top selling" as one and "mobile phone brands" as one. So it'll be "top selling mobile phone brands".

Comment: I understand it now, thanks Usman!